# How do I filter my gallery by toggled value from outside the gallery?

Tags: canvas, powerapps

I want to filter my gallery on the rows where the toggle is value is set to true. I want to do this from outside my gallery with a button. Does anyone know how to do this?

My app looks like this:

[image]

I tried the following:

In the button on the OnSelect property I coded : Set(varFilter,"filter")

In the gallery on the Items property I coded: If (varFilter="filter", Filter(myData, ToggleName.Value=true), myData)

Comment: could you not directly set on your onselect property of button `Filter(myData, ToggleName.Value=true)`

Comment: No that doesn't work unfortunatly. The reason for that (I think) is that the toggle value is not stored in the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your toggle value is not stored in the database, you could add a Collect() function to the toggles' OnCheck property. This way every time a user checks a toggle, that item will be added to a collection.

```
OnCheck: Collect(colCheckedItems, ThisItem)
```

Then on your filter button's OnSelect, change the gallery's data source to now show your collection.

OnUncheck you'll have to add a remove from collection statement as well.

---

On visible of the screen, set a variable to false.
Then on your button's OnSelect, toggle the variable between true/false:

```
If(varGalFiltered, Set(varGalFiltered, false), Set(varGalFiltered, true));
```

Update your gallery's Items property to switch the data source based on the variable:

```
If(varGalFiltered, colCheckedItems, myData)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What would the code be to filter the gallery on the created collection?

Comment: I just updated my answer, toggle a variable on the button click, then switch the data source based on the variable.